# Ng test throws an error Cannot find module 'angular-cli/plugins/karma'

Tags: angular

Using angular-cli trying to write a test for a service after executing **ng test**. I get this error:

```
02 03 2017 14:51:09.486:ERROR [config]: Error in config file!
 { Error: Cannot find module 'angular-cli/plugins/karma'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at module.exports (/Desktop/e2-frontend/karma.conf.js:12:7)
    at Object.parseConfig (/Desktop/e2-frontend/node_modules/karma/lib/config.js:342:5)
    at new Server (/Desktop/e2-frontend/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:56:20)
    at Promise (/Desktop/e2-frontend/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/test.js:34:33)
    at Class.run (/Desktop/e2-frontend/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/test.js:15:16)
    at Class.run (/Desktop/e2-frontend/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/test.js:106:25)
    at Class.<anonymous> (/Desktop/e2-frontend/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/models/command.js:134:17)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

**karma.config.js**

```
    // Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'angular-cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-remap-istanbul'),
      require('angular-cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    files: [
      { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false }
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      './src/test.ts': ['angular-cli']
    },
    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts','tsx']
    },
    remapIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: {
        html: 'coverage',
        lcovonly: './coverage/coverage.lcov'
      }
    },
    angularCli: {
      config: './angular-cli.json',
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
              ? ['progress', 'karma-remap-istanbul']
              : ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

It seems like it cannot find karma for some reason. there has to be a different location for it.
How can I fix this error?

Comment: What version of the angular-cli are you using?

Comment: I am using @angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.0

Comment: Take a look at the breaking changes: It's not angular-cli anymore, it should be @angular/cli

Answer (score 40):

Replace this line

---

```
frameworks: ['jasmine', 'angular-cli'],
```

**with this**

```
frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
```

---

This line

```
require('angular-cli/plugins/karma')
```

**to this**

```
require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
```

---

This

```
preprocessors: {
  ./src/test.ts': ['angular-cli']
},
```

**to this**

```
preprocessors: {
  './src/test.ts': ['@angular/cli']
},
```

in your `karma.config.js` file. Hope this will help you.

Comment: in one line: inside "karma.config.js" file of your project,  change "angular-cli" to  @angular/cli for every occurene

Answer (score 5):

**First**, make sure you install the latest angular CLI (npm install --save-dev @angular/cli:latest) and remove 'angular-cli' in package.json

**Second**, go to **karma.conf.js** edit the following:

**from**
frameworks: ['jasmine', 'angular-cli']

**to** 
frameworks: ['jasmine', @angular/cli']

**from**

```
require('angular-cli/plugins/karma')
```

**to**

```
require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
```

**from**

```
preprocessors: {
      './src/test.ts': ['angular-cli']
    },
```

**to**

```
preprocessors: {
      './src/test.ts': ['@angular/cli']
    },
```

**Then**, edit your angular-cli.json

**from**

```
"environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
```

**to**

```
"environmentSource": "environments/environments.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environments.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environments.prod.ts"
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

### Working solution

Open your **`karma.conf.js`** file and replace **every** **`angular-cli/plugins/karma`** with:

> **`@angular/cli/plugins/karma`**

The mentioned properties to replace are inside following keys:

- frameworks,
- plugins,
- preprocessors.

Then, the modified properties should look like:

```
frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
plugins: [
   require('karma-jasmine'),
   require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
   require('karma-remap-istanbul'),        
   require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
],
preprocessors: {
  './src/test.ts': ['@angular/cli']
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your package.json and make sure you don't have a line for "angular-cli".  If you do, remove it and run: npm install.  This cleared it up for me.  There was a reference for this in the dependencies and for "@angular/cli".  "@angular/cli" is the new location for the angular cli.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `"resolveJsonModule": true` into the file `tsconfig.spec.json` by the element `compilerOptions`. It worked for me.